# how to apply assign on a pandas rolling object?

Tags: python, pandas, assign

I am working with a pandas dataframe that has as index a timestamp. What I would like to do is calculate the columns 'A','B','C' from the dataframe on a rolling window of 2 months with a frequency of one month. The problem is that as I have to calculate the 3 columns simultaneously, I must use the assign function and it loos like I cannot run assign() on a rolling object. What would be the best way to solve this problem?

I'm sorry I cannot provide any sample data, but this what I essentially have to do:

```
df.rolling('2M').assign(
A = lambda x: do_something(x) + 1,
B = lambda x: do_something_else(x) + 3,
C = lambda x: do_somethingcool(x) + 6,
)
```

here's some sample data:

```
df.head()
                A        B              C
    date            
    2018-01-01  2.0     1.650000e+01    2.475000e+00
    2018-01-01  4.0     2.466667e+01    8.258333e+00
    2018-01-01  65.0    2.816667e+01    1.197708e+01
    2018-01-01  67.0    3.804167e+01    1.568958e+01
    2018-01-01  249.0   3.989881e+01    1.568958e+01
    2018-01-01  263.0   5.956548e+01    1.898958e+01
    2018-01-01  264.0   6.785119e+01    2.393958e+01
```

Comment: We need to see sample data and output in order to test and get clearer idea of what you'd like to do. It doesn't have to be your actual data, you can make it up.

Comment: @DarrenChristopher see my edit